# Schedule multiple tasks on multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduler

I need to perform some data collection periodically, for that I want to create a task which requests some data from different servers. Some servers will take more time to process the request and return the response than others.

That's why I want to create a task for each server and execute the tasks async. If i'm using `ScheduledExecutorService` in the following way will each task execute in its own thread or all the tasks will be executed in the same thread?

What happens if a task is throwing an exception all the other scheduled tasks will fail?

```
this.scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
                @Override
                public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                    return new Thread(r, "collectionThread");
                }
            });

for (String url:urls){
    this.scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new CollectorTask(url),
                                                  startupDelaySeconds,
                                                  scheduleRateSeconds,
                                                  TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a single-threaded executor service, so all tasks are being executed sequentially. If any of them throws an exception, all next tasks executions are cancelled.

You could use

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4)  // 4 is the max number of parallel jobs
```

... to allow parallel execution and wrap a body of a submitted job into

```
try {
    ...
} catch(Exception e){
    logger.warn("exception during task execution", e);
}
```

to log errors without propagating them.

Minor delays (several milliseconds) are possible and depend on the OS, tasks will never execute earlier than their scheduled time. Task's execution can be delayed due to previous long runs or lack of free threads, but the following executions will be run by the original schedule: `initialDelay + n * period`.

Comment: Is there, then, a way to execute the tasks async and to prevent the cancelling of the tasks after one is failing?

Comment: `If any of them throws an exception, all next tasks executions are cancelled.` I don't think so, the current executor thread will terminate, but a new one will be created by the executor.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev What happens if there are more than 4 tasks? Will the tasks wait for all the 4 threads to finish and start the execution of another 4 tasks or whenever one of the 4 tasks finishes another one will start (there are always 4 tasks running until they all finish)?

Comment: @Katona, this is the behaviour afaik, I'm trying to find JavaDoc for it.

Comment: @Katona - a scheduled executor will not reschedule a task that has previously thrown an exception.

Comment: This solution will work if you can tune the number of maximum parallel  jobs, but in my case it can vary and the density of servers preforming long processing is not negligible. So, I think, I can ran in the following situation: the long running tasks will fill the pool and the short running tasks will wait after them.

Comment: You need a cached thread pool then. You could forward all the jobs to a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` or hack `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to call a super constructor with `keepAliveTime` set to i.e. 60 seconds. One of the easiest way to do this I can think of is to copy `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` into your own version and change this parameter which is set to 0 and is not configurable in the original.

Comment: From my experience it's better to have some upper boundary, even if it is 500 or 1000 threads. This makes an app more predictable and saves cpu for thread switching which becomes essential for a higher number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you do is create two thread executors. The first is a scheduled executor which takes a runnable that is meant to start your actual runnable.  All this runnable does it create an instance of your task runnable and submit it to the real executor.  That executor should just be a normal thread pool that will handle the tasks.

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors
            .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    private class SubmitTaskRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            executor.execute(new TaskRunnable());
        }

    }
```

Schedule the SubmitTaskRunnable on your scheduled executor because that one will not throw any exceptions.  Let your actual task run inside a cached executor will allow multiple tasks to run concurrently even if the previous ones have not finished.